# Powershell invoke-restmethod then if statement off results

Tags: json, powershell

I have a working powershell script with invoke-restmethod. The results are pulling back a JSON result and I need to write some if statements off of it to take action. For example, if the status = done then I need to end the application, but if the status = in progress I need to wait 20 minutes then check another field called progressURL.

How do I extract the JSON values based on the key to use in an if statement?

Here is what I have: $response = Invoke-RestMethod WORKING REQUEST THAT RETURNS JSON

Here is the json response

```
{
  "status": done,
  "Links": {
    "AdditionalData": "someURL1",
    "Otherurl": "someURL2",
    "progressURL": "someURL3"
  }
"ID": 1
}
```

I just need to take $response that is in JSON and be able to extract values from it to use for if statements.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add your code so far, so that we have some context?

Comment: yes just updated it with a sample.

Comment: The json you pasted is invalid, which might be causing your problem.  If you put quotes around `done` and add another `}` at the end, then `ConvertFrom-Json` can turn it into an object that can be worked with.  You'll have to give the real `Invoke-RestMethod` command and the script you're using to run it if you want help determining if the problem is the server or your script.

Comment: I updated the JSON to be accurate. I accidentally deleted the last }. However, done in the response I get is missing quotes. Is that the cause of the problem? The text you see is exactly what I get back when I run a curl script minus me removing the urls.

Comment: I don't believe that not having the value in quotes makes it invalid JSON, is that just a powershell thing?

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` is choking on the word `done` without quotes, which may well be the problem.  I don't have a server available to test how `Invoke-RestMethod` behaves in this case.  After running your `Invoke-RestMethod` call above, what is `$response.gettype()`?

Comment: For what it's worth, jsonlint.com agrees with PowerShell on this point, as does http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp .  The REST server appears to be serving invalid json.  Not that this helps you out with your problem.  :(

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet to turn your result into a standard PowerShell object - from there it's just standard Boolean comparisons to get where you need to go.

Here's the documentation on ConvertFrom-Json to get you started:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx

Comment: invoke-restmethod does that "Windows PowerShell formats the response based to the data type. For an RSS or ATOM feed, Windows PowerShell returns the Item or Entry XML nodes. For JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) or XML, Windows PowerShell converts (or deserializes) the content into objects."

Comment: I am getting this error when I do that: ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .